# Get started to build a Widget

Tags: javascript, web-services, rest, grails, widget

I own a football community website (with RESTful web services available) written in [Grails](http://grails.org) and I would like to develop an **embeddable widget to be distributed into other websites or blogs**.

#### My requirements:

This widget (written in javascript/HTML rather than Flash since I don't know Flash) will display the latest articles of my website (easy...since I have RSS feeds available).

However, the most difficult part consists in having remote users to make predictions or give a rate to football games **directly from the widget itself**.
Two modes are supported : **anonymous user** or **user-authenticated** (user account located and managed on my website).

**Statistics from user actions of the client website** (i.e. the website embedding the widget) will also be reported inside the widget.

#### My solution:

Here you go! Where do I start? Do you advise me to go with **online widget creation tools** like [Widgetbox](http://www.widgetbox.com/make/), [KickApps](http://www.kickapps.com/widgets), [Widgadget](http://en.widgadget.com/node/add/widget), [Grazz](http://www.grazr.com/) or any other ones you like? If yes, which one is the easiest to use and enough flexible to fit my requirements ?

Or is there another simpler solution like a Grails plugin?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For something similar I have used Google Gadgets, which are very simple to create because you can use javascript with the API Google provides.

I wrote this post in my blog http://maricel-tech.blogspot.com/2008/11/how-to-create-google-gadget.html on how to create a google gadget that displays the news from CNN, it is a little outdated since Google changed their APIs, however the logic is the same you would just need to change the google method calls to use the new ones.

The example in the post reads the RSS feeds from CNN news and displays as a list the title and description of each article, in your case you would need to add some more logic to add the extra functionality you need, but I think you can find what you need in the Google API for gadgets.